# Python3: Only add new rows of an updated CSV File to MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am downloading the same CSV file multiple times per day with Selenium.  I am looking to append the contents of the new rows of this re-downloaded CSV file to MySQL every hour.

The original code I used prior to wanting to only capture the newly created rows in the CSV was:

```
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as  pd

data = pd.read_csv('CleanCSV.csv', sep=',', parse_dates=[0])
new_df2 = data.assign(time_stamp=datetime.datetime.now())
cnx = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost:3306/stats', 
echo=False)
new_df2.to_sql(name='stats', con=cnx, if_exists='replace', index=False)
print('Imported')
```

The above of course only just replaces the table and its contents, however I want to keep the original contents and only add new rows found in the CSV.

This code later evolved to (with a stackoverflow search):

```
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('Callbacks_Cleaned.csv', sep=',')
cnx = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost:3306/stats', 
echo=False)
for i in range(len(data)):
   data.iloc[i:i + 1].to_sql(name="callbacks", if_exists='append', con=cnx)
```

However this is not working. I keep receiving an integrity / primary Key:

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1062,
>   "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'")

Any guidance here is greatly appreciated here.